# Re-render geometry in three.js after a user changes the parameters with dat.gui

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, dat.gui

I'm trying to get a 3D spiral geometry to update in the canvas as the user uses a slider to change the number of coils. I've been using the dat.gui plugin as the interface. I can get it to work if I'm changing a parameter external to the geometry, like the x-scale, but if I'm trying to change a parameter that's internal to the geometry, it won't update. With console.log I can see that the updates occur in the information stored in the geometry, but the canvas doesn't update. Here's what I have for the dat.gui interface:

```
  const gui = new GUI()
  
  let guiControls = new function() {
    this.coils = 10
  }

  gui.add(guiControls, 'coils', 1, 15).onChange(regenerateGeometry)
  
  function regenerateGeometry() {
    let newGeometry = new THREE.Geometry()
 
    spiralSetup(newGeometry)

    mesh.geometry.dispose()
    mesh.geometry = newGeometry

    render()
  }
```

And here's what I have for the spiral geometry:

```
function spiralSetup(geometry) {
    for (let i = theta; i < t; i++) {
      let r = Math.exp((i / segments) * (1 / Math.tan(alpha)))
      let x = r * aa * Math.cos(i / segments) * Math.sin(beta)
      let y = r * aa * Math.sin(i / segments) * Math.sin(beta)
      let z = -r * aa * Math.cos(beta)
      
      geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z))
    }
  }
  
  spiralSetup(startGeometry)

  let material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0xBA42A5})
  let mesh = new THREE.Line(startGeometry, material)

  scene.add(mesh)
```

This jsfiddle includes all of the code: https://jsfiddle.net/yjsnhf72/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that you were updating the coils in the guiControls class but not updating the variable `coils` and then updating the variable `t`. Here's the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/635n924s/)

Comment: That took care of it! Thank you!